# How do I spoof a host locally (for testing)?

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, spoofing

Is it possible to spoof a host for testing?

The site that I'm working on is set up to detect the requested url and render branded assets. So for instance, www.aaa.com and www.bbb.com both point to my web app, but it detects that www.aaa.com was requested, so it loads the correct assets for that brand.

The problem is that I don't know how to effectively test this. My first instinct was to just add www.aaa.com to my host file and have it resolve as 127.0.0.1:64099 (for instance), but you can't specify ports. How else can I go about this without actually having to publish to IIS or a site running on port 80?

Comment: But how do I set that up to work with functional testing? I'm basically just testing pages through the web browser. Or rather... am I gonna have to put that stuff in IIS for each branded test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add both urls to the host file. Port does not need to be specified there, and will still work:

```
127.0.0.1 www.aaa.com
127.0.0.1 www.bbb.com
```

From the browser, type:

```
http://www.aaa.com:64099
http://www.bbb.com:[port num]
```

The above assumes your sites are bound to specific host names (www.aaa.com, etc) and port numbers.

Comment: Ok so I tried this and the first part worked. It displayed the correct page, but the application is still recognizing the request as "localhost". Any thoughts?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic - I'm not quite sure what you mean, so I am taking a guess here. When you "view source" on the page are there links (hrefs) to "localhost"? If so, you'll have to change the way your app generates links.

Comment: Sorry. In the app, I need to see what the user typed into their browser. So if they typed www.aaa.com I need to be able to see that for the rest of my mechanisms to trigger and load up the correct resources. At this moment, the fact that www.aaa.com was requested seems to be lost. When I set a break point in the methods that need this info, request.Url.Host (and everything else for that matter) shows "localhost". Does that make more sense? I'm thumbing through other properties in the request object and I'm not seeing any trace of the original request url (www.aaa.com)

Comment: @Sinaesthetic - you have to use some variation of `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Get("Host")` instead of `Request.Url.Host`. I does return the port number though so you will have to deal with that.